# Can I place TextField on TableView header-column on javafx 2

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am newbie on javafx. Can anybody help me to add some TextFields on TableView header. I try it with put TableView on stackpane and place textfields on above it, with the help of css integration. Can't success.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this.

*For JavaFX 2.2*

In JavaFX 2.2 (jdk7u6+) jira [RT-14909](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14909) was implemented, which allows you to set a graphic (arbitrary node) on a column to specify the table header for the column.

```
TableColumn col = new TableColumn("");
TextField colHeaderTextField = new TextField("Pink Elephants");
col.setGraphic(colHeaderTextField);
```

*For JavaFX 2.0 and 2.1*

After you have added the table to an active scene and it has been rendered, you can lookup the table header labels and change them to display a graphic (which can be any kind of node) which displays textfields for the table headers rather than the default static label text.

Here is a sample:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithTextHeaders extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName"));

    TableView table = new TableView();
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
      new Person("Ethan", "Williams")
    ));
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().add(table);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    for (Node n: table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label")) {
      if (n instanceof Label) {
        Label label = (Label) n;
        TextField textField = new TextField(label.getText());
        label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
        label.setGraphic(textField);
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
      }
    }
  }  

  public static class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

    private Person(String fName, String lName) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
      this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much jewelsea. I am your fan. Before I am a web apps developer using spring & jsf. I have impressed your wordpress blogs and going forward to javafx, evenif javafx has lot of limitations(don't care now because javafx is newbie). I got stuck on your jquery calender as trick of webview, fine. I like jquery, hope to integrate full strength of jquery for javafx templating. Obviously I have explain My goal is to develop a TableView with filter on tableheader like jquery implementation of Primefaces. Exactly this, http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

Comment: for (Node n: table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label")) {
      if (n instanceof Label) {
        Label label = (Label) n;
        TextField textField = new TextField(label.getText());
        label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
        label.setGraphic(textField);
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
      }
    } .. I try         label.setGraphic(textField); and         label.setText(label.getText); Not work both(graphics & Text). Otherwise I try to place Text and TextField on VBox and label.setGraphics(VBox), error..

Comment: I try a different approch, its not good. Place TableView on StackPane and create HBox with TextField's corresponding to TableView columns. On css make double height on header(.table-view .column-header{-fx-size: 56px;}), and place that HBox above to TableView header part. But unfortunately I can't correct tableview each column-header width and each TextField width has same size.

Comment: This does not work. I still see the old labels. Moreover for 2.2 setting the graphic won't work since the size of the column will be off.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about Adam.  I ran the code using both methods on JavaFX 9.0.4 and they seemed to work fine to me.  I don't know what you mean by "I still see the old labels" (I am not sure what old labels are) or "size of the column will be off" (sizing appears fine to me).