# JavaFX - searching row in tableview by column

Tags: search, javafx, tableview, row

I have a tableview and possibility to search by single column, [e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6sA6.png)

Problem starts when I have a lot of columns and there has to be a lot of text fields for each column. Is there easy way to make something like first row in the tableview is row of editable search boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a row of text fields, one per column, you may want to place a HBox container above the TableView and put TextField instances into the HBox. In order to get the sizing right, you may bind the text field (preferred!) widths to the respective column widths, and the HBox (preferred!) width to the TableView widht:

```
hbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableview.widthProperty());
textfield1.prefWidthProperty().bind(col1.widthProperty());
textfield2.prefWidthProperty().bind(col2.widthProperty());
```

A quite simple but effective approach for the filtering would be to wrap the TableView data in a FilteredList and update the filter predicate if the text within one of the search boxes changes:

```
ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data.add(....); // add data ...

// wrap the data collection in a filterd list:
filteredList = new FilteredList<>(data);
filteredList.setPredicate(p -> true); // Initial: show all rows

// set the FilteredList as TableView data:
tableview.itemsProperty().set(filteredList);

// Create a changelistener for the search box:
// "dataObject" is an instance of your data class/entity etc.
 textfield1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
  updatePredicate();
});
textfield2.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
  updatePredicate();
});
```

If your columns do not fit in the TabelView's viewport, then you might want to place the search boxes in the column header, i.e., set the TextFields as graphic property to the TableColumn:

```
col1.setGraphic(textfield1);
col2.setGraphic(textfield2);
```

At first, the graphic node will hide the column title. You may try to correct this via css styling (just a hint, I'd need to check this out), or you pack a new Label together with the textfield in a HBox that will be the column header graphic node.

Method for updating the filter predicate:

```
private void updatePredicate() {
  filteredList.setPredicate((data) -> {
      boolean showItem = true;
      if (!textfield1.getText().isEmpty()) {
        showItem = showItem && (data.getField1().contains(textfield1.getText()));
      }
      if (!textfield2.getText().isEmpty()) {
        showItem = showItem && (data.getField2().contains(textfield2.getText()));
      }
  return showItem;
  });
}
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I've already have this part. The problem is how to create a row full of text fields where I can type things to search for each column. I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I updated the answer accordingly (I hope).

Comment: That's the solution I have right now :D 
Column resize policy is set to UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY, so with a lot of columns I have a slider at the bottom of tableview, and textfields in HBox don't look good then

Comment: OK, I understand. If the columns don't fit in the TableViews viewport, then my suggested solution does not help. An alternative may be placing the TextField nodes in the column headers, e.g. as described there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525311/can-i-place-textfield-on-tableview-header-column-on-javafx-2. This is a JavaFX 2,x topic, I'd need to check it if it is still valid for JavaFX8.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here a draft example where the search works by AND logic, i.e. all search texts are taking into account.

Assume you have a persons as data model:

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }
}
```

The table is designed as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051.MyCellValueFactory?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051.Controller">
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefWidth="600">
        <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
        </columnResizePolicy>

        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="First Name">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <MyCellValueFactory property="firstName"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>

            <TableColumn text="Last Name">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <MyCellValueFactory property="lastName"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>

            <TableColumn text="E-mail">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <MyCellValueFactory property="email"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

We have custom table row classes.

**MyTableRowData:**

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

public abstract class MyTableRowData<T> {
    public abstract T firstNameProperty();

    public abstract T lastNameProperty();

    public abstract T emailProperty();
}
```

**SearchTableRowData:**

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class SearchTableRowData extends MyTableRowData<ObjectProperty<String>> {
    private final ObjectProperty<String> firstName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<String> lastName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<String> email = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

**PersonTableRowData:**

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

class PersonTableRowData extends MyTableRowData<ObjectProperty<String>> {
    private final ObjectProperty<String> firstName;
    private final ObjectProperty<String> lastName;
    private final ObjectProperty<String> email;

    PersonTableRowData(final Person person) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person.getFirstName());
        this.lastName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person.getLastName());
        this.email = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<String> emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

The **MyCellValueFactory** class is a heart of all magic:

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MyCellValueFactory<P extends MyTableRowData<?>, S extends Node>
        implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<P, S>, ObservableValue<S>> {
    private final String property;

    public MyCellValueFactory(@NamedArg("property") final String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<S> call(final TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<P, S> param) {
        final P tableRowData = param.getValue();

        if (tableRowData instanceof SearchTableRowData) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(buildSearchTextBox(tableRowData));
        } else if (tableRowData instanceof PersonTableRowData) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(buildText(tableRowData));
        }

        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private S buildText(final P tableRowData) {
        final Text text = new Text();
        text.textProperty().bind(extractProperty(tableRowData));

        return (S) text;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private S buildSearchTextBox(final P tableRowData) {
        final TextField searchTextField = new TextField();
        searchTextField.promptTextProperty().set(property);
        searchTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(extractProperty(tableRowData));

        return (S) searchTextField;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Observable> T extractProperty(final P tableRowData) {
        try {
            final Class<?> c = Class.forName(tableRowData.getClass().getName());
            final Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(property + "Property");

            return (T) method.invoke(tableRowData);
        } catch (final Exception exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller** class:

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TableView<MyTableRowData<?>> tableView;

    private final ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<MyTableRowData<?>>> observableRows =
            new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    private final SearchTableRowData searchTableRowData = new SearchTableRowData();

    private final List<Person> originalPersons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("A", "B", "c@c.com"),
            new Person("AA", "BB", "cc@c.com"),
            new Person("AAA", "BBB", "ccc@c.com"),
            new Person("AAAA", "BBBB", "cccc@c.com"));

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        tableView.itemsProperty().bind(observableRows);

        observableRows.getValue().add(searchTableRowData);

        searchTableRowData.firstNameProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> fillPersons());
        searchTableRowData.lastNameProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> fillPersons());
        searchTableRowData.emailProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> fillPersons());

        fillPersons();
    }

    private void fillPersons() {
        ((ObservableList) observableRows).remove(1, ((ObservableList) observableRows).size());

        observableRows
                .getValue()
                .addAll(originalPersons
                        .stream()
                        .filter(getFirstNamePredicate())
                        .filter(getLastNamePredicate())
                        .filter(getEmailPredicate())
                        .map(PersonTableRowData::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private Predicate<Person> getFirstNamePredicate() {
        final String value = searchTableRowData.firstNameProperty().get();
        return StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(value) ?
                person -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(person.getFirstName(), value) :
                person -> true;
    }

    private Predicate<Person> getLastNamePredicate() {
        final String value = searchTableRowData.lastNameProperty().get();
        return StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(value) ?
                person -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(person.getLastName(), value) :
                person -> true;
    }

    private Predicate<Person> getEmailPredicate() {
        final String value = searchTableRowData.emailProperty().get();
        return StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(value) ?
                person -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(person.getEmail(), value) :
                person -> true;
    }
}
```

Finally you run all together by this **Main** class:

```
package com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.javafx.q54280051;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.dmaslenko.stackexchange.stackoverflow.q54033646.CsvReader;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final URL fxmlFileResource =
                CsvReader.class.getResource("/com/dmaslenko/stackexchange/stackoverflow/javafx/q54280051/main.fxml");
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlFileResource);
        final Parent rootPane = loader.load();

        loader.getController();

        final Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is draft but working example, without much optimization.

The known areas to improve:

1. any change in search fields lost the focus and cursor.
2. the first row is selectable but should not.

Answer (score 0):

just a complement to our friend Robert Rohm's answer, which was very useful to me.
In my case I have a textfield for several columns following change:

```
private void updatePredicate() {
    filteredList.setPredicate((procura) -> {
        boolean showItem = true;
        if (!txtPesquisaCliente.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Cliente cliente = (Cliente) procura;
            String procurado = cliente.getCnpj() + " " + cliente.getCpf() + " " + cliente.getEmail()
                        + " " + cliente.getNome() + " " + cliente.getFantasia() + " " + cliente.getRg()
                        + " " + cliente.getIe();
            showItem = showItem && (procurado.contains(txtPesquisaCliente.getText()));
        }



        return showItem;
    });
}
```