# Javafx - Put some textfield in the first row or header - tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview

Can i add a text field on each column for filtering. [image: like the image bellow.]

Comment: The answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525311/can-i-place-textfield-on-tableview-header-column-on-javafx-2)

Comment: thanks for finding the duplicate :)